# Jackson adds empty object in front of arrayList during deserialization

Tags: json, spring, jackson

I have a simple POJO (ProviderModel).
When I deserialize a list of this objects (see code: List providers) an empty object is added in front of the JSON. 
I am using Jackson 1.9.13 ans Spring 3.0.7

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/provider/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public List<ProviderModel> updateLongList(@RequestBody ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> models,
        HttpServletRequest request) {

    List<ProviderModel> providers = new ArrayList<ProviderModel>();

    for (Map<String, Object> model : models) {

        ProviderModel providerModel = new ProviderModel();
        providerModel.setId((int) model.get("id"));

        long rfpId = Long.parseLong((String) request.getSession().getAttribute("rfpId"));
        MYLOG.info("rfpId = " + rfpId);

        long listId = ProviderListLocalServiceUtil.findLongListforRfP(rfpId);
        User user = null;
        long userId = 0;

        try {
            user = OsdeUserUtil.getUserFromCookies(request);
            userId = user.getUserId();
        } catch (PortalException | SystemException | EncryptorException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        long providerId = providerModel.getId();            

        // add to LongList
        try {

            ProviderListEntryServiceUtil.addProviderListEntryByListId(listId, userId, providerId);
            providers.add(providerModel);

        } catch (SystemException | PortalException e) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        MYLOG.info("Provider hinzugefügt " + model.get("id") + "/" + model.get("name"));
    }

    return providers;
}
```

And this is the response:

```
{}
 && {
    "providerModelList": [{
            "id": 1502,
            "name": null,
            "location": null,
            "description": null,
            "imagePath": null,
            "detailUrl": null,
            "providerStatus": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Any ideas or hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake!
**@RespondBody** is missing in the method signature:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/provider/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public @RespondBody List<ProviderModel> updateLongList(@RequestBody ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> models,
            HttpServletRequest request) {...}
```